# Exact column width

Tags: jquery, css

I try to build a table using jQuery. The table should have columns with exact widths.

Let say the first column width should be exactly 100 px, including padding (10 px on each side). I tried many combination of functions `width()` and`innerWidth()`, but I will describe two attempts:

1. I create td and set `td1.width(100);`. 
   Then the function `td1.width()` returns 120 px and function `td1.innerWidth()` returns 140 px. The column width according to Firefox console is 140 px.
2. I create td and set `td1.innerWidth(100);`. 
   Then the function `td1.width()` returns 100 px and function `td1.innerWidth()` returns 120 px. The column width according to Firefox console is 120 px.

Why function `td1.width(100);` works in such a strange way?

But the main question is: is there any possibility to get column with 100 px width? So set width which will really include padding?

.js file

```
var bodyTable = $("<table>");
var body = $("<tbody>");
var tr1 = $("<tr>");
var tr2 = $("<tr>");

$("#testTable").append(bodyTable);
bodyTable.append(body);
body.append(tr1);
body.append(tr2);

var td1 = $("<td>foo</td>");
var td2 = $("<td>foo</td>");
var td3 = $("<td>foo</td>");
var td4 = $("<td>foo</td>");
var td5 = $("<td>foo</td>");
var td6 = $("<td>foo</td>");
tr1.append(td1);
tr1.append(td2);
tr1.append(td3);
tr2.append(td4);
tr2.append(td5);
tr2.append(td6);

td1.width(100);
console.log(td1.width(), td1.innerWidth());    //Result: 120 140

td1.innerWidth(100);
console.log(td1.width(), td1.innerWidth());    //Result: 100 120
```

.css file

```
#testTable td {
  padding:10px;
}
```

.html file

```
 <div id="testTable"></div>
```

Comment: Why aren't you doing this all in CSS, instead of jQuery?

Comment: Because I generate many tables and the column width depends on the data I generate from (eq tables include day of the month). The second thing is that I try to build a table with separated header and body, so the header cah have fixed position over the body (scrillable body) -- in this case I need to have exact numbers so the body can correspond to the header.

Comment: Look into CSS box sizing: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp This will help calculating sizes with padding.

Comment: Look at JQuery's .width() documentation here https://api.jquery.com/width/ to see what it really returns. Details nicely.

Comment: @NawedKhan I tried, but got no effects. But documentation helps: "this may require retrieving the CSS width plus box-sizing property and then subtracting any potential border and padding".

Comment: give them class names and handle it with css.

Comment: Right. That seems to be the best option. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of inner width might confuse you but in fact, the innerwidth is the **width + padding**. You have 100px width + 10px padding all around which makes it 120px in total width (100+10left+10right).

This picture is the complete guide of what each width, innerwidth, etc ... means.

[image]

**NOW** here in my snippet you see I created one red box with the width of 100px and the blue one is in the red box with 10px padding for red box. but still the blue box is 100px because the red box becomes 120px. And also notice the blue box does not have padding so the innerWidth and width will both be 100px.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".reddims").append("<p>inner width: " + $(".red").innerWidth() + "</p>");
    $(".reddims").append("<p>width: " + $(".red").width() + "</p>");
    $(".bluedims").append("<p>inner width: " + $(".blue").innerWidth() + "</p>");
    $(".bluedims").append("<p>width: " + $(".blue").width() + "</p>");
    $(".bluedims").append("<p>Because Blue doesn't have paddings.</p>");
});
```

```css
.red {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: red;
}
.blue{
background-color: blue;
width: 100%;
height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red">
<div class="blue">
</div>
</div>
<div class="reddims">
<p>Red Dimensions are: </p>
</div>
<div class="bluedims">
<p>Blue Dimensions are: <p>
</div>
```

**BUT AT THE END** For your case you can do this instead. And do whatever you want with the designing. This will give you more freedom of what you can do  with designing.

```
var td1 = $("<td class='td1'>foo</td>");
var td2 = $("<td class='td2'>foo</td>");
var td3 = $("<td class='td3'>foo</td>");
var td4 = $("<td class='td4'>foo</td>");
var td5 = $("<td class='td5'>foo</td>");
var td6 = $("<td class='td6'>foo</td>");
```

I hope that explains your question.

**PICTURE CREDIT :** https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dimensions.asp

Comment: Thanks. I applied the "BUT AT THE END" option ;)

Comment: Yw :) Glad to be a help